# JFreeChart adding annotation to Gantt chart

Tags: annotations, jfreechart, gantt-chart

I use Jfreechart for one week and I would like to add some annotations next to the bars in the Gantt chart. I know that it is possible for XYPlots and CategoryPlots but I don't find the solution for Gantt charts.

Can you help me ?

Thank You ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [`GanttChart`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/src-html/org/jfree/chart/ChartFactory.html#line.1322) has a [`CategoryPlot`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/plot/CategoryPlot.html), so just use a [`CategoryAnnotation`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/annotations/CategoryAnnotation.html).